# Spring MVC: Inheriting controllers

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Within my web application I have a tool for generating PDF/XLS reports. These "reporters" inherit from a basic controller and they just describe the reporting functionality, something like:

```
public abstract class Reporter {

    getPath() {
        return "/reporter/" + getClass().getSimpleName().replace("Reporter", "").toLowerCase() + ".{pdf|xls}";
    }        

    handleRequest() {
        // prepare the data
        generateReport(...)
        // do something with it
        // then report pdf or excel
    }
}

@Controller
public class DailyReporter extends Reporter {
    @Override
    void generateReport(...) {}
}

@Controller
public class AverageReporter extends Reporter {
    @Override
    void generateReport(...) {}
}
```

In this way I can just describe the data for each Reporter.

Using Spring MVC, the `getPath()` method is actually part of the Annotation, but using `getClass().getSimpleName().toLowerCase()` in the annotation is not possible as it needs to be "Compile time constant". Is there a way to do this with Spring MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use inheritance. Use composition/delegation.

Have a single controller, mapped to `/reporter/{type}.{pdf|xls}`. Define an interface `Reporter`, and one spring bean implementing that interface per type of report. Inject a `List<Reporter>` in your controller. And for each request, find the reporter responsible for the type passed in the URL, and call it.